# Detected dependencies problem

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, build

I cannot build the solution. The error output is:[image]

Looking at other people's suggestions pointed to missing dependencies. So I checked it:

[image]

The properties of a file like Dsofile.dll points to a location on the hard drive. I have checked it and the SourcePath is correct and it is marked as "Exclude" because unmarking it leads to another error. The Dsofile.dll cannot be shared in GAC. So where's the error? The list of dependencies is longer. There is about another 10 SI.ArchiveService.*.dll files.

Answer (score 2):

Dsofile.dll is inprocess COM Server for those who use .NET to interact with Office documents when Office is not installed. But, to do so, one has to install this file. It can be done following
[this link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9BA6FAC6-520B-4A0A-878A-53EC8300C4C2&displaylang=en).

Do you have installed MS Office? Maybe that is the problem. Also, there are several missing files as can be seen on screenshot (MDIVWCTL.DLL - it is used for Microsoft Office Document Imaging), PDFCreator.exe, etc. You definitely should check if missing assemblies exist on your machine, and if so, change paths to them. But, I suppose that COM Servers don't exist or they are not registered since they should be found if they are properly registered. My recommendation is to reinstall missing components.

Comment: I have manually installed those files. The Dsofile, the pdfcreator and the Office extension is all located correctly on the hard drive. When I look at the properties for them, the SourcePath points to the correct location. So I don't know what to do from here:-(